# How can I get a user's home country using the PHP facebook SDK

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api

So far I can get information about the user's hometown:

```
$userProfile = $this->_facebookRequest->getGraphObject(GraphUser::className());
```

Then I can extract out the page for their hometown (hometowns do not seem to be castable to GraphLocation):

```
$homeTownPageId = $userProfile->getProperty('hometown')->getProperty('id');
```

Then I can get that page:

```
$pageRequest = (new FacebookRequest($this->_facebookSession, 'GET', '/' . $homeTownPageId ))->execute();
```

Then I'm stuck. If you actually go to a location page, they look like [this](https://www.facebook.com/pages/New-York/112825018731802?nr=109837349041959). Over on the top right you can see it clearly says 'United States'.

How can I extract out that information using the facebook SDK? I have tried casting the page to a `GraphLocation` and using `getCountry` but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

When you construct the login button *(for example with <fb:login-button>)* you must determine in "scope" attribute which fields do you plan to read. Some fields are public, some not.
For example if you want to rearch the *hometown* field you must use facebook button like here:

<fb:login-button autologoutlink="true" **scope**="public_profile,email,**user_hometown**"></fb:login-button>

Parameters (permissions) used in "**scope**" are these:

**PERMISSIONS**: public_profile (Default), user_friends, email, user_about_me, user_actions.books, user_actions.fitness, user_actions.music, user_actions.news, user_actions.video, user_actions:{app_namespace}, user_activities, user_birthday, user_education_history, user_events, user_games_activity, user_groups, user_hometown, user_interests, user_likes, user_location, user_photos, user_relationships, user_relationship_details, user_religion_politics, user_status, user_tagged_places, user_videos, user_website

**EXTENDED PERMISSIONS**: read_friendlists, read_insights, read_mailbox, read_page_mailboxes, read_stream, manage_notifications, manage_pages, publish_actions, rsvp_event

See documentation: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/v2.2